# How do I make my ORDER BY DESC queries efficient in MySQL if descending indexes are ignored?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE from_user=? AND to_user=? ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

`created_at` is a datetime column.

According to my previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862598/do-i-need-to-index-primary-key-if-i-use-it-for-order-by-desc)), I learned that you don't need to create a descending index.

Is this index ok if I have billions of records? (notice I'm not specifying a desc index for created_at)

```
>> from_user_id, to_user_id, created_at
```

Comment: Yes as long as you follow the order of where clause as per the indexing i.e. from left to right the indexing should be taken into account. I have a similar table not billion but few millions and the explain plan shows nice result on similar query.

Answer (score 0):

IMO having an index on  `from_user_id, to_user_id, created_at` would not help you much. 
I don't think you have many records with the same `from_user_id, to_user_id, created_at` values. (date time with millisecond!)
If my assumption is correct, in the index  with such a low cardinality the effectiveness is reduced to a linear search plus wasting storage.
 I will suggest having an index on `from_user_id, to_user_id`, matching your where criteria, the index will be applied before ordering.
In any case you can see the [query execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to see the query cost, when having these indexes.
 ([indexing mechanism overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work) is interesting)